# Unity 3D: Graphics.DrawMesh not working in Unity 5.3.1f anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a simulation using GIS data to represent the map of a small city, using a constant mesh and a mesh-renderer on most of the objects (grey and blue in the images). But some elements like houses or sewage drains are sometimes highlighted by using a mesh and UnityEngine.Graphics.DrawMesh function.

[image]

As you can see in the pictures, the same code used in 4.6.1f renders the mesh, while in 5.3.1 it's not. Though you can see the Mesh is set in the Scene view.

This is the code:

```
protected Mesh m;

public void Update()
{
    if ((isActiveAndEnabled) && (m!=null))
        Graphics.DrawMesh(
            m, transform.localPosition, 
            transform.localRotation, material, 14); //14 = Map Layer
}
```

Scene and Camera settings stay the same. I already checked if the *if ((isActiveAndEnabled) && (m!=null))* condition is true - it is. Any thoughts what might cause this problem?

Comment: Unity3D 5.x has many bugs. Might be one of them. Just check the normals of mesh, maybe they are flipped.

Comment: Say Jerry you could make your first sentence more accurate by removing the "5.x"  :)

Comment: I feared it might just be Ol' Buggy Unity again :/ Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow Hehe, but I really feel that 4.5.x and later till 5.x was really stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Map and HighlightedAreas both lay on `transform.position.z = 0;` While this wasn't a problem in Unity *4.6.1* I assumed it won't be one in *5.X*.

[image]

I tried moving the Parent Object *Highlight* closer to the camera, but since I used `localPosition` it didn't affect the child. Moving the child I was able to see the highlighted areas and realized my fault.

Code changed to

```
Graphics.DrawMesh(
        m, transform.position, 
        transform.localRotation, material, 14);
```

and changed the parent object *Highlight*'s `transform.z` to `-0.01f`